# About fullPage.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullpage.js

I'm working with [fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/), an amazing scrolling framework.

I need to have the site working like this:

[image]

As you can see in the .jpg when the site loads and people click or scroll to the right using the slideshow, there are 4 slides there, when they catch the last one users can only go down. No other behavior is allow.

Now I have this working just for the horizontal line, in the following way:

- People can not go back because there is no previous button.
- When people get to the last horizontal slide the next button navigation disappear.

Now I need to create another section down and I need that one just works on the last slide numbered as 4 in the jpg. Not allow to pass there in the slide 1, 2 or 3.

Any ideas? How can I do that?

Comment: You can see the project: 

http://next.dharmawebstudio.com/new-next/

As you can see users can go down in the first, second and third slide. 

I want that just in the fourth slide users can go down. 

Any ideas. ?

Comment: Just to inform you that the (project) link you provide gives a "500 Internal Server Error".

Answer (score 0):

You could disallow the vertical scrolling until the user reach the last slide.

You could use the functions [`setAllowScrolling`](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#setallowscrolling) and [`setKeyboardScrolling`](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#setkeyboardscrolling) provided by the plugin together with a callback such as ['afterSlideLoad'](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#afterslideload-anchorlink-index-slideanchor-slideindex).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for reply.  I found a solution changing the framework and working with Parallaxjs.

http://stolksdorf.github.io/Parallaxjs/

Very versatile for this purpose. !